# How to ensureIndex a list of geometry

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I have a mongodb collection as below

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId(...),
  "gemetryCollectionId" : 1,
  "geometry" : [{
      "type" : "Polygon",
      "coordinates" : [[[2, 3], [4, 4], [4, 3], [2, 3]]]
    }]
}
```

How do I ensure index for the geometry list?

It doesn't work, If I do it like

```
db.collectionName.ensureIndex({"geometry":"2dsphere"});
```

Comment: what is the error that it is showing ?

Answer (score 0):

You are giving geometry as an array. Try creating the index by creating it as an object only. something like this:

```
{   
  "_id" : ObjectId(...),   
  "gemetryCollectionId" : 1,   
  "geometry" : {
      "type" : "Polygon",
      "coordinates" : [[[2, 3], [4, 4], [4, 3], [2, 3]]]
   } 
}
```

It will work then.

Thanks